# How to make parameter combination of integer and tuple value in itertools.product()?

Tags: python, python-itertools

Evening everyone, i want to ask itertools. I have my code for doing some manual grid search in word2vec parameter optimization. Here what is look like :

```
from gensim.models import word2vec
import itertools

parm_dict = {
    'workers' : (4),
    'size' : (300,500,750,1000),
    'min_count' : (40),
    'window' : (10)
}

workers, size, min_count, window = [tup for k,tup in parm_dict.items()] # Individual parm tuples

parm_combo = list(itertools.product(workers, size, min_count, window)) # Create all combinations
```

The problem is, ittertools.product can't make iteration on workers because it detected as integer not a tuple. it shown error :

```
int type is not iteratable
```

Is there any way for me to make parameter combination between Integer value and tuple value? or maybe there is another way to improve this? Thank You

Comment: `(4)` is just 4. But `(4,)` is a 1-tuple of 4.

Comment: `'workers' : (4)` is not a tuple it should be `'workers' : (4,)`

Comment: If i `wrote 'workers' : (4,)`, is it detected as single value or 4 and 0?

Comment: Thank for the asnwer by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To distinguish parentheses literal from the tuple, add a trailing comma

```
parm_dict = {
    'workers' : (4,),
    'size' : (300,500,750,1000),
    'min_count' : (40,),
    'window' : (10,)
}
```